# Not able to use a MailChimp popup

Tags: wordpress

Since this post got flagged as off-topic on WordPress StackExchange, I'll try my chances here.

[My original post on StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/310711/edit)

Recently I tried integrating a mailchimp popup. The code is directly generated by mailchimp, I'm not editing it whatsoever.

I've tried implementing it several ways.

1. On the page via RAW JS.
2. Via a plugin called "Header & footer scripts".
3. Via a custom JS box in the Theme Options (this rendered a syntax error.) [image: Screenshot of the error]
4. via wp_enqueue_scripts in my child functions.php, which also generates an error in the console. [image: Screenshot of the error]

This is the script:

[image: Official code screen from MC website]

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data- 
dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script 
type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], 
function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us18.list- 
manage.com","uuid":"d86301311141426b96c33360e","lid":"c46a6060b8"}) })</script>
```

I'm not really sure if I'm allowed to ask this question here, but I'm at my wit's end.

As far as I'm aware there is a syntax error in the code somewhere, but then again I wonder, why would MC push out code with an error.

I've already contacted MailChimp about this issue, they told me that the code looks fine and that there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried linting the code?  Also the the error in #4 shows it might be a related file `mailchimp_popup.js`

Comment: I've tried, and the mailchimp_popup.js file is the file in which I put the code and enqueued it via the wp_enqueue function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code itself. The problem is when you copied and pasted you introduced line breaks which were not there. I ran the following and it works.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script 
type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], 
function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us18.list-manage.com","uuid":"d86301311141426b96c33360e","lid":"c46a6060b8"}) })</script>
<?php
 } );
```

Observe data-dojo-config and mc.us18.list-manage.com

Probably you have configured your editor to do auto word wrap on hyphens which will not work when editing code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me out, I've tried putting this code into my functions.php (child theme). But this renders my website blanco, when I remove the code it's accessible again.

I'm probably going to look for other options (maybe via a plugin). Anyways, you're answer will probably work, but I think there's something ulterior, maybe the theme is incompatible.

I've already found a fix that that the script is looking for jquery.js is the root folder, but WordPress puts it inside the wp-includes. I've already fixed that the jquery is also accessible via the root folder.